# Compiler can't identify my variable

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, nested-loops

I'm running this simple program to play around with arrays and nested for loops. For some reason my compiler can't identify the variable "r"? I don't know why it is doing this. Any suggestions?

```
public class ForLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[][] mat = new int[4][8];

        for(int r=0;r<mat.length;r++);
        {
            for(int c=0;c<mat[r].length;c++)
            {
                mat[r][c]=r*c+c/2+r*(c+1);
            }
        System.out.println(mat[0][2]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon terminates the `for` body immediately (as an empty expression) here

```
for(int r=0;r<mat.length;r++);
{ //<-- not part of the for.
```

remove the semicolon so that the next block is part of the `for` loop

```
for(int r=0;r<mat.length;r++) {
```

Comment: Oh ok I see now. I'm an idiot haha thanks for the help!